# Go Fiber and HTMX - HX-Trigger header is changed to Hx-Trigger, which is not what HTMX is listening for

Tags: go, htmx, go-fiber

I have a very simple to-do app with a form and a list of to-dos, built in Fiber and HTMX. When the user adds a new to-do via the form, I want HTMX to refresh the list of todos.  I know I can use `hx-swap-oob`, but then I'm returning the new To-Do as part of my form partial, and that doesn't feel correct.

According to the [HTMX Docs](https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#events), I can set an `HX-Trigger` response header.

So, in Fiber, this is what the code for my `POST /todos` handler looks like:

```golang
func (h *TodoHandler) Create(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // do stuff to create the todo and persist it...

    c.Context().Response.Header.Set("HX-Trigger", "newTodo")
    return adaptor.HTTPHandler(templ.Handler(partial.TodoForm(&td)))(c)
}
```

This seems to work, but the header is being set to `Hx-Trigger`, not `HX-Trigger`. How can I force Fiber (or the underlying fasthttp) to respect the casing for the header name?

[image: Picture showing the header name as Hx-Trigger]